# Include all characters using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace, innerhtml

i'm not very familiar with regular expression, and i'm trying to solve a problem in pure Javascript.

i'm using `replace()` tu cut out a string into words (divs), then words into letters (span), to animate all the letters separately

But using my code below, only letters are taken into consideration.
I need to include everything (alphanumeric, special characters, ...)

```
<p class="string">Hello! My name is John Do.</p>
```

```
.about-line {
 border: solid 2px blue; 
  display: inline-block;
}
.letter {
 border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```
var cutText = document.querySelector(".string");
cutText.innerHTML = cutText.textContent.replace(
  /\w+/g,
  (word) =>
    '<div class="about-line">' +
    word.replace(/./g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
    "</div>"
);
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `/\w+/g,` matches letters, digits and underscores. You need to adjust this part to what you actually need.

Comment: If you want to wrap _every_ character into a span, including whitespace characters - then just use `/.+/g`. Or, if you want to wrap everything but whitespace characters, use `/\S+/g`

Comment: @CBroe Wouldn't need regex replacement for `/.+/g`

Comment: Thank you all for your help!
@CBroe Thanks! `/\S+/g` is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match 1 or more non whitespace characters `\S+` to get all the "words", and then still use the dot to get every character (as you only have non whitespace characters left in that match)

```js
var cutText = document.querySelector(".string");
cutText.innerHTML = cutText.textContent.replace(
  /\S+/g,
  (word) =>
  '<div class="about-line">' +
  word.replace(/./g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>") +
  "</div>"
);
```

```css
.about-line {
  border: solid 2px blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.letter {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<p class="string">Hello! My name is John Do.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! 
`/\S+/g` was indeed what i was looking for !